# How to generate text ASCII art

Tags: ascii-art

How can I generate ASCII text like this:

```
<!--
             ,--.                                                                 
   ,--.  ,--.`--' ,---. ,--.   ,--.     ,---.  ,---. ,--.,--.,--.--. ,---. ,---.  
    \  `'  / ,--.| .-. :|  |.'.|  |    (  .-' | .-. ||  ||  ||  .--'| .--'| .-. : 
     \    /  |  |\   --.|   .'.   |    .-'  `)' '-' ''  ''  '|  |   \ `--.\   --. 
      `--'   `--' `----''--'   '--'    `----'  `---'  `----' `--'    `---' `----' 


                                 ,---. 
     ,---.                       |   | 
    /    | ,---.,--.  ,--.,--,--.|  .' 
   /  '  || .-. :\  `'  /' ,-.  ||  |  
   '--|  |\   --. \    / \ '-'  |`--'  
      `--' `----'  `--'   `--`--'.--.  
                                 '--'

  -->
```

Comment: Google for ASCII art editor or something like this...

Comment: Search the internet for "ASCII art".

Comment: You need a text editor with a fixed width font

Comment: Google for `figlet` (figure letters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

> http://www.network-science.de/ascii/

Answer (score 3):

This site looks good for what you are willing to do

> http://www.kammerl.de/ascii/AsciiSignature.php